# Dynamic Scoping and static scoping

Tags: dynamic, static, scoping

[image]

I do not understand this can anyone answer this and explain if possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting because I am looking into this myself on a program to walk a tree recursively.  Specific to your question I have found the following to be the most concise and clear demonstration:
https://msujaws.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/static-vs-dynamic-scoping/

The exact same code produces different results.  The key lies in the bar method where b is set to 2.  In static scoping int b is declared in the method stays local to that method.  When foo is called the int b declared in bar is not in scope but the higher level const b is and is used both times.

In dynamic scoping scope is resolved up the call chain so the int b in bar is used in the call to foo.